# Linux : Activating twice the same module with differents parameters

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-module, analog-digital-converter

I'm working with two ADS7828 ADC with I2C Interface.
I'm on a Debian with a 3.4.67 kernel and use the ADS7828 module for Linux.
To enable this module and control the component, I write :

`modprobe ads7828 int_vref=0 vref_mv=3347`

`echo ads7828 0x48 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device`

and need to configure the second ADC with a 5000 vref_mv, can I enable the same module twice ? And if so how ?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't use stack exchange any more but did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this answer later I found it on Redhat's site: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Setting_Module_Parameters.html

> For example, if you wanted to load the Intel PRO/1000 network driver
>   with the interrupt throttle rate set to 3000 interrupts per second for
>   the first, second and third instances of the driver, and Energy
>   Efficient Ethernet (EEE) turned on ⁠[5], you would run, as root:

```
~]# modprobe e1000e InterruptThrottleRate=3000,3000,3000 EEE=1
```

so presumably you could do

```
~]# modprobe ads7828 int_vref=0 vref_mv=3347,5000
```

Although those parameters appear to have disappeared somewhere between 2.6 and 3.10, the ads7828 driver no longer has parameters I can find.